# IDNS vulnerability in URL

Tags: php

As I was trying enter the URL with beginning with dot of kind •
I tried to enter in my browser like •facebook.com n finally it get converted into form of xn--example--.com

Steps of reproduction

A very unusual vulnerability related to idns n punnycode cant understand about this behavior. 
Entering just a appended dot of kind ◦is converting every site into idn format.i too reported at ibb also. Its affecting all the sites on internet.

http://xn--hackerone-pf2f.com/redirect?signature=3d7fd60fad8705f1518b40929941a1dc3b7baa73&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxn--thefacebook-s17g.com%2F

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But what is your question?

Comment: Its quite simple why adding • before any of the url converts it into punny code n idn format?

Comment: Because it's not ascii-safe, so it's converted into puny code

Comment: Does it possess any risk or not?

Comment: Does it have any relation to homograph idns attacks?

Comment: If a browser would not show puny code but the unicoded one - then yes

Comment: Browsers convert punycode to unicode just fine, and most browsers have a blacklist of bad characters that could possibly cause homograph attacks. ◦ may even be on said blacklist, as when I when I go to ◦hackerone.com, my browser converts it to the punycode address.

So, again, what's the security concern here?